# Import Products...Root out Duplicates

Tags: php, csv, e-commerce

I want to import about 2,000 products but I already have some of them in my store.

What's the best way to only add the new unique products and avoid creating duplicate products?

I can't compare some model names, SKU's or EAN's of my current products with the new products as some of them don't match.

Have CSV and XML sources. Using Opencart3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to find out which attributes must be the same for a product to count as a duplicate of another one.

> I can't compare some model names, SKU's or EAN's of my current
>   products with the new products as some of them don't match.

If it's not model names, SKUs or EANs then its something else. To find out what these attributes are is up to you, we can't help here.

You will have to read these attributes of each new product, search the DB for an existing one with these attributes, and then if there is no match, create a new one.